# Google Fit supported wearable devices

Tags: google-fit

Where might I find a list of the supported wearable devices for Google fit?
That is all I want to know.
Where might I find a list of the supported wearable devices for Google fit?
That is all I want to know.
Where might I find a list of the supported wearable devices for Google fit?
That is all I want to know.

Comment: I have the same question, have you found any answers? ty

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a similar topic, but as long as the watch has Google Play Services that should probably support Google Fit.